# youtube iframe api loadVideoById() error

Tags: iframe, youtube-api

I am adding youtube video to a companies website and would like them to display on non-flash devices. I have been playing with the youtube iframe API and updated one of their examples to allow a user to click on a link to change the video in the iframe. The edited code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<body>
<div id="player"></div>
<script>
var tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.src = "http://www.youtube.com/player_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
var done = false;
var player;
function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
      height: '390',
      width: '640',
      videoId: 'JW5meKfy3fY',
      events: {
        'onReady': onPlayerReady,
        'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
      }
    });
}
function onPlayerReady(evt) {
    evt.target.playVideo();
}
function onPlayerStateChange(evt) {
    if (evt.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && !done) {
        setTimeout(stopVideo, 6000);
        done = true;
    }
}
function stopVideo() {
    player.stopVideo();
}

function loadVideo(videoID) {
  if(player) { player.loadVideoById(videoID); }
}

</script>

<a href="javascript:loadVideo('kGIjetX6TBk');">Click me to change video</a>

</body>
</html>
```

The only thing I added was:

```
function loadVideo(videoID) {
  if(player) { player.loadVideoById(videoID); }
}
```

This works fine in Safari, Chrome and Firefox but does not work in IE7, 8 or 9. In IE7 and 8 it returns an error "Object does not support this property or method".

Is this an issue with the API or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 8):

I had a similar problem, and it turned out that you shouldn't call any of the methods on the YT.Player object (including `loadVideoById`) as long as `onPlayerReady` hasn't been called.

Doing a check `if(player) {...}` isn't sufficient, the `Player` object will be created and some properties will already be available in out without the methods you need being available.

Comment: Solved it. `... events: { 'onReady': function() { ...}`

Answer (score 3):

You will need to call the load video function from the onPlayerReady event.

For example, if you want to load a video when clicking a thumbnail do this (this would require jquery but it should get the point across):

```
function onPlayerReady(evt) {

  evt.target.playVideo();

  //declare the click even function you want
  $('#thumbs a).click(function(){

    //get a data-video-id attr from the <a data-video-id="XXXXXX">
    var myvideo = $(this).attr('data-video-id');

    //call your custom function
    loadVideo(myvideo);

    //prevent click propagation 
    return false;
  });
}
```

This way you can be sure the player is loaded.

Comment: Hey, I was facing the same problem. I am sure that onPlayerReady has been called before I am calling loadVideo(). I am not calling loadVideo in the onPlayerReady function though. I am calling it in onPlayerStateChange function. What can be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Preventing click propagation with `return false` after the call to `player.loadVideoById` in my click event handler did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

Use player._player.loadVideoById(yourvideoid) for manually triggering event by id